# form layout broken in Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

Can ayone explain why my form is broken in Firefox? I have tried various ways to correct it, but keep getting the same result. I would be grateful if someone could tell me where I am going wrong with it. I have included grabs so you can see the problem. I have also posted the code at fiddle. I also note that at fiddle i am using IE8 and the layout is broken there also but not in my broswer. Many thanks.

Grabs:

http://img20.imageshack.us/i/ffformincorrect.png/

http://img195.imageshack.us/i/ie8formcorrect.png/

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tdfLQ/

Comment: I copied this locally and they look the same, also. You should never use IE as a reference for how things work. Always get things working in a modern browser first. Then look to see how IE screws things up.

Comment: @rob the reverse normally works quite well for me. if it works in IE then the tweaks in modern browsers are minimal. thanks

Comment: You're going against the grain. No web developer does it that way and neither should you. IE is years behind all others in modern standards and practices. You are testing against a broken browser but trying to make the modern browsers conform to it. That practice will continue to give you many ongoing problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your jsfiddle link in Firefox,Safari,Chrome and IE 8 and they all render it the same way, and Aziz' solution just require some tweaks, try looking at: http://jsfiddle.net/tdfLQ/1/

In addition to removing the width like Aziz suggested, I have just added margins to the fields and send button.

A quick google came up with this page, which looks helpful (maybe a little old): http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/forms/

Answer (score 1):

Remove `width: 350px;` from `.fb-input-right-con`

Comment: if you look at the fiddle code once that change is made, the input boxes lose there layout properties. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/tdfLQ/8/